# autocomplete text with add missing value

Tags: php, jquery

I have a textbox which fetches the names using autocomplete functionality of JQuery. Suppose if value is not found it should allow the user to add it to the DB, so that the next time its fetchable. The addition may be like if not found an add button appears to add it to DB and the users process with the rest of the transaction process. The portal is being developed using PHP as server side scripting and SQL Server as back-end DB and for frontend validations and others I am planning to use JQuery.

How can this be done?

For autocomplete I am referring to: http://www.codexworld.com/autocomplete-textbox-using-jquery-php-mysql/

Please advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Jquery AutoComplete Plugin` has the `response` event , which can be used to detect the returned results, in a general case it would be something like :

```
$(function(){
   $('input').autocomplete({
       source : <your_dataa_source>
       response : function(event,ui){
         if (ui.content.length === 0) {
                // add the element
            } 
     }
});
```